# Https doesn't work with the SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, debian, configuration-files

I finally come to ask for your help. I actually lost hope against this issue.
I set up a first vps, with different domains (3x), all configured with SSL mod and everything is working well, permanent redirection from HTTP to HTTPS as well.

Unfortunately, I copy/paste this configuration into a second vps,and re-build all certificates and changed all virtual host settings. Everything is working well, except the SSL (https). And in the error or access log file, I found no errors regarding this...

On each browser, it's not working, I get a time out...If I checked on sslChecker, everything is ok but the certificate doesn't seems to be recognized for the domain www.------.be

Do you have any idea to help me please ?

Note: My default file (virtual host) is also configured for this website (like on my first configuration)

the test openssl connection return the following code :
- Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)

Thank you in advance !

The virtual host file :

```
        <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin postmaster@bubul.be
        ServerName bubul.be
        ServerAlias www.bubul.be

        DocumentRoot /var/www/bubul.be/

        Redirect permanent / https://www.bubul.be/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/bubul.be/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/bubul.be/
        ServerName bubul.be
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/bubul.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/bubul.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Edit: I found the solution, finally after reading your book, I saw to make two certificate for two domain, and also for apache configuration, make it twice and then it works ;)

Thanks a lot for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Checking with s_client gives the certificate and I see the following errors:

- the certificate is self-signed, so browsers will not accept it by default and complain.
- the certificate is only for bubul.be, not for www.bubul.be, so browsers will complain about hostname not matching certificate.
- the certificate does not have X509v3 Extended Key Usage set to TLS Web Server Authentication, which means that browsers will not accept this certificate as a server certificate. Often this results in the browser just hanging around or giving some strange error, because a basic assumption about certificates is not met.

Comment: *"the certificate does not have X509v3 Extended Key Usage"* - that requirement shows up in [CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements](http://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/Baseline_Requirements_V1_1_9.pdf) Appendix (B)(3)(F). EKU is optional in [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt). Is anyone using the CA/B to enforce policies? I generally avoid it because it causes problems in some Java validators.

Comment: From my experience all browsers require this setting and you get very strange errors if it is not provided. SSL libraries for programming languages on the other side mostly don't care.

Comment: Did I do something wrong in the command to get this kind of error ?
I suppose yes, I saw in documentation to read "multiple domain with one certificate", is that right ?

Comment: You have to add the appropriate settings to the openssl config file. See http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName, https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#Extended_Key_Usage_